# how to add two fields as foreign key to a table?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I have two tables "team" and "match". every team can be on different matches and every match contain two or more teams and so it's a manytomany relation.
here is my match model:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    result = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    winner = models.??????
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name='team')
    referee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='referee')
```

the winner of every match is also a team but I don't know how to handle it. should I define it as foreign-key to team table? what is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `related_name` argument specifies the back relation from your intermediate table, use:

```
winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='winning_team')
```

Edit: Nico actually named the related_name logically better, as one would access the `match`es_won from the `team` object.

Comment: ManyToManyField is incorrect here, as it is a ManyToOne relationship. ForeignKey is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='matches_won')
```

Comment: So just to elaborate on this, OP the winner is a many-to-one relationship, so you need a simple foreign key relation to store the winning team. The related_name helps specify how you will access the `match` object from a `team` object